# Fundamental Solution of a heat equation with a drift term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, greens-function, fundamental-solution

Let consider the following equation on $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}$:
$$
    \partial_t u + \beta \partial_x u  =
\alpha \partial_{xx} u.
$$

**Question:** Is it possible to construct a fundamental solution for this equation ?

I was thinking in reformulate it under the form:
$$
    \partial_t u + \partial_x  ( \beta u - \alpha \partial_{x} u    ) =
0.
$$

What strategy do you think is the appropriate to obtain a Green-like function for this equation ?

Comment: [Hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4157963/949989).